# What is the difference between a Double ended linked list and a Circular linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was asked to solve a problem using a double ended linked list and a circular linked list.

I know the double ended linked list has two pointers at the head node, one pointing to its next node and the other pointing to the last node. This idea seems to be very similar to that of the circular linked list. Are the two any different from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a circular linked list, the first node (head) points to the last node and the last node points to the first node.

[image]

While in a double-ended linked list, each node has just one pointer which points to its next node. it contains two pointers of this kind ("first" and "last"), so you are able to insert elements to the list from both ends of it. Also, you are able to track the last node faster through its pointer

[image]

**Highlight: Double-Ended - first points to last node
           Circular - first and last node point to themselves**

Comment: Can you please clarify how in circular linked list first node and last node point to themselves. I guess it's only true if there is only one node otherwise it should be like "the last node points to the first node".

Comment: Second image is no longer being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In the circular linked list, the last node of the linkedlist will point back to the first node of the linked list. But in case of double ended linked list we will have two pointer which will point to starting node and the end node, which will help in insertion at both starting as well as end.
You can check these for references.
References
[circular linked list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/circular_linked_list_algorithm.htm)

[difference between double-ended linked lists and doubly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329680/difference-between-double-ended-linked-lists-and-doubly-linked-list)

Comment: this is not a doubly linked list, it is a double ended linked list. They are not the same

Comment: it was a typo i meant double ended linked list, but written doubly linked list.